# Problems with User Management - Kubuntu 16.04

Tags: kubuntu, 16.04, user-management

I have one user set up (in addition to myself.) I want to add another one.In user management (in settings) I can't see the user I've already set up! Also, I entered details of another user, which were accepted - but this user doesn't appear on the log-in screen! HELP!
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by installing kuser package :

```
sudo apt-get install kuser
sudo kuser
```

Gives me full access to user and group management

Comment: It doesn't work for me.  kuser and gives "Error opening /etc/shadow for reading" error

Comment: @lboullo0: What's the output of `ls -l /etc/shadow`?

Answer (score 0):

I had same problem today. The lines in the shadow-files of `group` and `gshadow` for the new user (e. g. `ny`) are missing. Compare:

- `~/ sudo less /etc/group` – `~/ sudo less /etc/group-`
- `~/ sudo less /etc/gshadow` – `~/ sudo less /etc/gshadow-`

In `/etc/group` you find:

```
ny:x:1001:
```

As admin copy & paste this to `/etc/group-`. Same procedure with

```
ny:!::
```

in `/etc/gshadow` to `/etc/gshadow-`.

Then it worked for me.